# How do I get the data passed via Safe Args to show in a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to pass data from an item clicked from my RecyclerView. I believe I have followed the instructions provided by android [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data). The issue I am having is when I click on the item, navigate to the fragment, the textviews are not displaying that data I passed.

Below is my code. Thanks for your help.

Navigation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/viewJournalEntry">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/viewJournalEntry"
        android:name="us.jordanakellogg.journalapplication.ui.ViewJournalEntry"
        android:label="ViewJournalEntry" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_viewJournalEntry_to_journalEntry"
            app:destination="@id/journalEntry" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_viewJournalEntry_to_entryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/entryFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/journalEntry"
        android:name="us.jordanakellogg.journalapplication.ui.JournalEntry"
        android:label="JournalEntry" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_journalEntry_to_viewJournalEntry"
            app:destination="@id/viewJournalEntry" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/entryFragment"
        android:name="us.jordanakellogg.journalapplication.ui.EntryFragment"
        android:label="EntryFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="title"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="date"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="body"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

RecyclerView adapter where I try to pass the data.

```
class JournalAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<TextItemViewHolder>() {
    var data = listOf<Journal>()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }



    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TextItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        holder.textView.text = formatJournalEntry(item)

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(

                ViewJournalEntryDirections.actionViewJournalEntryToEntryFragment(
                    item.entryTitle, convertLongToDateString(item.entryDate.timeInMillis),
                    item.entryText
                )
            )
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TextItemViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_item_view, parent, false) as
                TextView

        return TextItemViewHolder(view)
    }
}
```

And lastly my destination fragment where I attempt to set the text views equal to the parameters that were passed.

```
class EntryFragment : Fragment() {

    val args: EntryFragmentArgs by navArgs()



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: FragmentEntryBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false)


        binding.title.text = args.title
        binding.date.text = args.date
        binding.body.text = args.body

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, container, false)
```

Which is returning a brand new inflated layout, not the `binding` you've been working on. Instead, return the root of the binding you've been using:

```
return binding.root
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your adapter.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TextItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        holder.textView.text = formatJournalEntry(item)

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(

                ViewJournalEntryDirections.ActionViewJournalEntryToEntryFragment(
                    item.entryTitle, convertLongToDateString(item.entryDate.timeInMillis),
                    item.entryText
                )
            )
        }

    }
```